# Арифметика указателей в индексную форму Си

Tags: c

Как можно преобразовать обращение через адресную арифметику:

```
(*((*(*(((*arr) + k) + j)) + 2) + 3) + i);
```

в индексы массива:

```
arr[...][...][...][...];
```

Comment: А в чём вопрос? Вы не знаете как работает оператор []?

Comment: Сначала покажите, как объявлен `arr`. Или "скрытость" объявления `arr` является частью задания?

Answer (score 4):

Обращение по индексу — это синтаксический сахар над адресной арифметикой. То есть эти три записи эквивалентны:

```
foo = bar[i];

foo = *(bar + i);

foo = *(тип bar-а)((char*)bar + i * sizeof(bar[0]));
```

Иными словами, каждое разыменование (оператор звёздочка) — это новая пара квадратных скобок.

Зная это, можно спокойно переходить к преобразованию вашего выражения. Для этого начинаем движение из самого глубокого подвыражения в скобках и двигаемся наружу:

1. `*arr`

   Разыменовывание указателя. `*arr <=> *(arr + 0) <=> arr[0]`. Первый индекс получили.
2. `(*arr) + k <=> arr[0] + k`

   Разыменования нет, так что пока собираем второй индекс.
3. `((*arr) + k) + j <=> (arr[0] + k) + j`

   Продолжаем сбор индекса. По приоритету операторов `(arr[0] + k) + j) <=> arr[0] + k + j`, а по их смыслу (предполагаем, что `arr[0]` — это указатель) `arr[0] + k + j <=> arr[0] + (k + j)`. `(k + j)` — это индекс согласно эквивалентностям в начале ответа.
4. `*(((*arr) + k) + j) <=> *((arr[0] + k) + j) <=> *(arr[0] + (k + j))`

   Разыменовывание. Заменяем адресную арифметику на разведанный индекс: `*(arr[0] + (k + j)) <=> arr[0][k + j]`. Новый индекс приписываем справа, так как:

   1. Индексы вычисляются и применяются слева направо.
   2. Исходное выражение вычисляется изнутри скобок наружу.

   То есть порядок записывания скобок должен совпадать с порядком разбора нами исходного выражения.

Ну и так далее по аналогии.

---

В результате получаем, что `(*((*(*(((*arr) + k) + j)) + 2) + 3) + i);`, то есть:

```
(
    *(
    |   (
    |       *(
    |       |  *(
    |       |  |    (
    |       |  |        (*arr) + k
    |       |  |    ) + j
    |       |  )
    |       ) + 2
    |   ) + 3
    ) + i
);
```

превращается в `arr[0][k + j][2][3 + i]`. Разумеется, переменная должна поддерживать такое количество разыменований, то есть иметь тип `T****`, где `T` — это некий значимый тип.

Comment: Переменная может также иметь и тип `T [a][b][c][d]`, и тип `T (*(*)[b])[d]`, и т.п. Все эти типы отличны от `T ****`.